# Regular expression for first instance of a quoted string

Tags: regex, notepad++

What regex do I use to select the first instance of a string in single quotes when the line contains multiple comma separated single quote values ?

There could be multiple lines and **I want to match *first instance* on *each line***.

`‘(.*?)’` selects all instances so the lazy quantified is not working exactly as I expected

Here’s an example of [what I’m seeing](https://regexr.com/727sp):

```
Fucntion(12345, 'ThisOneOnly', 'NotThis', 'NotThisEither');
Fucntion(12345, 'ThisOneOnly', 'NotThis', 'NotThisEither');
Fucntion(12345, 'ThisOneOnly', 'NotThis', 'NotThisEither');
```

Comment: Thank you. On  further evaluation, it didn’t work for every line. Only for first line.

Comment: @Silver.Rainbow It's often quite essential to mention the tool/lang you're using along with regex questions. :)  Added the Notepad++ tag to your question if that's ok.

Comment: if it did not work for every line that is most likely related to how you are parsing the file/data

Comment: Why are you giving an example with javascript while you're working with Notepad++ ? Could you give (**as text**) a sample file and expected result.

Comment: Did anything work for you? Please add details to the question if not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the global modifer. Click on Flags and remove global, so it's `/'(.*?)'/` instead of `/'(.*?)'/g`

**Edit**

Notepad++ doesn't allow replacing only first match per line. So you need leave the rest untouched:

```
Search   '.*?'(.*)
Replace  \1
```

This solution is simple, but I found [Wiktor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411051/845034) to be faster.

Comment: Thank you. This didn’t work in notepad++  btw.   The regex within the forward slashes doesn’t work and I’ve not been able to find a way to turn of the global flag in notepad++

Comment: It also works only for first line of the global flag is removed

Comment: You should process your input linewise. I'm sorry, I don't use notepad++; but it works in ..say .. vim (different syntax though).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have updated the regexr.com example in my original post to show what I’m seeing just in case you want to see the issue I’m talking about.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But you should apply a regex to each line instead of processing the content as one long string with line-breaks in-between. The latter is less performant and has it's limits. In vim e.g., that regex translates to this substitute command: `:%s/\v'(.{-})'//` (different syntax, but same logic). Applying this removes the first function argument _for each line_ (`%`). I am very sure, you can and should do the same in Notepad++. `:%s/\v'(.{-})'//g` on the other hand would remove _all_ function arguments in all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^.*?'\K.*?(?=')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regexr.com/727sp).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `'` - a `'` char
- `\K` -  match reset operator that discards all text in the match memory buffer
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=')` - a positive lookahead that requires a `'` to appear immediately to the right of the current location

Probably a bit more efficient variation of the same regex will be

```
^[^'\n\r]*'\K[^'\n\r]*(?=')
```

where `[^'\n\r]` finds any char other than `'` and LF/CR chars.